# Reduce php server requests

Tags: php

Probably a very stupid question, but I'm wondering how php works. I'm trying to find ways to improve the php of my WordPress themes.

```
<?php
echo "PHP script.";
?>
<?php
echo "More PHP script!";
?>
```

Will I reduce the number of requests/processes if I put them together like this

```
<?php
echo "PHP script. More PHP script!";
?>
```

What I actually want to know is will there be a request to the server every time there is a < ?php and can I or do I reduce the number of requests by combining them?

Comment: Number of requests depending on the amount of `<?php` - no. But the amount of times it needs to be parsed; yes.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with requests. // And even if you changed it for parse time’s sake – that won’t have any effect that you could measure or even notice. So better don’t even start with changing things in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you understand what a "request" is in this context, and you may be mixing terminology (which is leading to your confusion on the matter).

To answer the question... No, having multiple lines of PHP code in a single file does not perform additional HTTP requests.

When you make a request to a URL, such as:

```
http://www.example.com/somePage.php
```

That creates *one* request.  The server-side code in `somePage.php` is processed *in its entirety* and the *result* of that processing is sent to the client in response to the request.  At this point the request/response is done.

The request has literally *nothing* to do with how many lines of PHP code are on the page.

> I'm trying to find ways to improve the php of my WordPress themes.

Well, in order to do that you first would need to *identify* something that needs to *be* improved.  Don't just randomly shuffle your code around and hope it makes things better in some immeasurable way.  *Measure* something, then improve that something.

If your page is loading slowly, find out where/how/why that's happening.  Maybe you have some code that's taking a long time to process, maybe you have inefficient SQL queries, maybe you're transferring large images to the browser and the network is slow, maybe something else.  Don't *guess*, *measure*.

Comment: "I'm not sure you understand what a "request" is in this context". You're right, I don't have a clue, but your answer helped me. I'll have to find to right way to measure what is causing many processes to run at the same time and why sometimes php hangs and slow down my website. Don't know if that's easy on shared hosting?